# mvc url pattern (hide controller and param keys)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, url-routing, routeconfig

I have a project in .net 4.5 Mvc on vs 2015.
there is an action with params such as `../Catalog/Category?Src=Trendings&order=Mostpopular`
in my url I don't want to show name of the controlller and "?" 
this code should look like this:

```
../Trendings
```

or `../Trendings/Mostpopular`
or `../Catalog/Category/src/Bestseller/Trendings/order/Mostpopular`

How can I write route configs for this?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attribute routing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).
Learn more about customizing routes [here.](http://johnatten.com/2013/08/21/customizing-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/)